# How can I add Wikidata properties of item a on the Wikipedia page of item b?

Tags: wikipedia, wikidata

How would I get the eccentricity ([Property:P1096](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Property:P1096)) of Venus ([Q313](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q313)) in the article [en:Mars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mars)?

I have figured out that I have to write `{{#property:P1096}}` if I want to get a property of the page on that page, but another pages property seems not to work.

### What I've tried

None of these worked:

- `{{#property:P1096|of=Q313}}` <- includes the property of the current page
- `{{#property:P1096|id=Q313}}` <- includes the property of the current page
- `{{Q313#property:P1096}}` <- messes up

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [v0.4 of the Wikidata inclusion syntax](https://meta.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?title=Wikidata/Notes/Inclusion_syntax_v0.4#Properties_of_different_items), this feature has not been implemented yet. The [progress of this feature](https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T49930) is available in the [Wikimedia bug tracking system](https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/).

Answer (score 3):

And just to add to the others, now it is available on English Wikipedia, and you would use it like this: `{{#property:P1096|from=Q313}}`

Answer (score 2):

To add to Patrick's answer, "arbitrary access" to Wikidata items from other Wikipedia pages is now available:

https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:Arbitrary_access

It's currently (14 May 2015) live only on French Wikisource and Dutch Wikipedia; next week it will go live on Farsi Wikipedia, English Wikivoyage, and Hebrew Wikipedia; and if all goes well will be rolled out on all projects in June.